# Strings comparison fail for two characters

Tags: string, assembly, x86, string-comparison, masm

I have this macro:

```
compare macro string1, string2
    local equal, notequal
    mov eax, 1 
    mov ecx, 4
    lea esi, offset string1
    lea edi, offset string2
    cld
    repz cmpsb
    je equal
    jmp notequal
    equal: mov eax, 0
    notequal:
endm;
```

If string1 is "A+B" and string2 is "A+B" all works great and eax is 0.
Also working for "A-B" or "AxB" ..

Why is this not working for comparing "AB" with "AB" ?

PS. I am using MASM and I prefer to not use C/C++ functions

LATER EDIT:

```
string1 db "AB"
operation db 6 dup(0)
```

where operation is string2 and I read it from keyboard
using this macro:

```
read macro var, typee
    push offset var
    push offset typee
    call scanf 
    add esp, 8
    mov esi, eax
endm
```

where var is actually operation and typee is a => string db "%s", 0

Comment: I _suspect_ that you are comparing four bytes. When you have three characters plus terminating `'\0'`, all four bytes are the same. When you have two characters plus `'\0'`, you may find yourself with an uninitialized fourth byte, which will in general be different… Can you confirm that "hard coding" `AB\0\0` works?

Comment: Hardcoding with two `\0` will definitely work.

Comment: I just added an "Later edit" if string1 would be string1 db "AB\0\0" and i a_file would be also (from keyboard) "AB\0\0" it works.. but I need it to make it work only with AB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to see your precise definition and contents of `string1` and `string2`.

If you are null-terminating the strings (ie the last value is a 0-byte) then the reason is that in the `A?B` cases, you are comparing 4 characters, including the last (zero) byte. If you use `AB` then the third will presumably be a zero, but what is the fourth? It must match.

---

edit to specify possible cure

```
string1 db "AB"
        db 2 dup(0)  ;to fill out string1 to 4 bytes
operation db 6 dup(0)
```

Comment: The byte sequence for `string2`==`operation` will be `A B \0 \0.....` but for `string1` will be `A B A B`. You'd need to fill out string1 to the length you are matching (4) with bytes of 0.

Answer (score 0):

The `repz cmpsb` instruction will tell you how many character in the string are equal up to the number of bytes in `ecx`.

If you compare a string with the same size as indicated in `ecx` then your code works, but if the strings are shorter, like in your second example, it means that the instruction will loop until the third byte (which is probably `\0` to terminate the string) and then might hit a byte which is not equal anymore, thus the loop is broken earlier and your branch is not taken.

So if you want to compare strings of arbitrary size you can take the length and put it in `ecx` and they are equal only if `ecx == 0` after the comparison.

If you have strings of different length, then you know already that they can not be equal.

Actually it is good for you that the fourth byte happen to not match, because it is undefined, and you would think your code works fine, if there happen to be `\0`  bytes at the end accidently at the right position.

Comment: but I actually don't know the size of the string .. it could be A+B or AB also .. i need to make it little bit dinamically. PS. it also can be "detA"

Comment: Of course, so you'd have to get the stringlength. Either that, or you'd have to loop manually. As I said, the cmp instruction will only tell you how many characters satisify your comparison. That is not enough to tell if two strings match.